# Solana openbook-dex createMarket script

Tags: typescript, solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana

I am unable to create a new market on openbook-dex. I am trying to get the createMarket.ts script from their example repo (https://github.com/openbook-dex/scripts-v2/) to function. It is not clear from the example what values should be set for all parameters, as there are a number of commented out lines. Code below as I am executing it, with the commented lines removed and loading a helper script where I load the rpc. I have been using the solana devnet for my tests. I have minted a new token for this test, and using that address for the baseMint, and the authority loaded via the keyphrase json is the mint authority for that token.

```
import {
  Keypair,
  PublicKey,
  ComputeBudgetProgram,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
  Connection,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  AnchorProvider,
  BN,
  Program,
  Wallet,
  getProvider,
} from "@coral-xyz/anchor";

import { createAccount } from "./solana_utils";
import { MintUtils } from "./mint_utils";
import { OpenBookV2Client } from "@openbook-dex/openbook-v2";
import { RPC, authority, connection, programId } from "./utils";
import { HTTP_URL, WSS_URL } from "./constants";

function delay(ms: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function main() {
  const wallet = new Wallet(authority);
  const provider = new AnchorProvider(new Connection(HTTP_URL, {wsEndpoint: WSS_URL}), wallet, {
    commitment: "confirmed",
  });
  const client = new OpenBookV2Client(provider, programId);

  console.log(
    "starting with balance: ",
    await provider.connection.getBalance(authority.publicKey)
  );

  const baseMint = new PublicKey("EoSHYd5zpfZDkC33gssK98sy8Q3QGXKkVaAwsEAqBTZi"); //Base Mint: Your token mint address.

  //SOL
  const quoteMint = new PublicKey("So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"); //Quote Mint: The token you wish to pair with your token.

  const oracleAId = null;
  const oracleBId = null;

  const name = "VVCT-SOL";

  const [ixs, signers] = await client.createMarketIx(
    authority.publicKey, // payer
    name, // name
    quoteMint, // quoteMint
    baseMint, // baseMint
    new BN(1), // quoteLotSize
    new BN(1000000), // baseLotSize
    new BN(0), // makerfee
    new BN(0), // takerfee
    new BN(0), // timeExpiry
    oracleAId, // oracleA
    oracleBId, // oracleB
    null, // openOrdersAdmin
    null, // consumeEventsAdmin
    null, // closeMarketAdmin
  );

  const tx = await client.sendAndConfirmTransaction(ixs, {
    additionalSigners: signers,
  });


  console.log("created market", tx);
  console.log(
    "finished with balance: ",
    await connection.getBalance(authority.publicKey)
  );
}

main();
```

and the contents of my helper script:

```
const NETWORK = "DEVNET"; //DEVNET or MAINNET
export var HTTP_URL = '';
export var WSS_URL = '';

if (NETWORK == "DEVNET") {
    HTTP_URL = "https://api.devnet.solana.com";
    WSS_URL = "wss://api.devnet.solana.com";
} else if (NETWORK == "MAINNET") {
    HTTP_URL = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";
    WSS_URL = "wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";
}
```

when run, this returns:

```bash
(node:4183492) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
starting with balance:  980597400
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "#<Object>".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

the rejection is happening in the sendAndConfirmTransaction call, but the error isn't helpful in determining why.

I found a successful transaction to the same program on devnet here: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3JkmfJE6tKoodGhRkQaq4dP4LXSw3Je8rQCw6X7YW4qB6HT4mAqxk1HPGpLGhgQ6ce1w3WwPmR3wUNcq1FeD6zpz?cluster=devnet but it is not clear to me why mine fails. Based on the successful transaction, I have also tried setting `oracleAId` and `oracleBId` to `new PublicKey("opnb2LAfJYbRMAHHvqjCwQxanZn7ReEHp1k81EohpZb")`, which is the openbook v2 programId, but I get the same error.